# How to omit an association during save that is a part of may_to_many relationship in Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using GORM to connect to mysql DB and have a schema with many to many relationship between two tables. When I try to save the entity where the relationship is defined, it also tries to insert the other entity which is part of the association.

My model:

```
type Language struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
}

type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
  Languages []Language `gorm:"many2many:user_languages;"`
}
```

Code sample:

```
var languages []Language
err := db.Find(&languages).Error
if err != nil { panic(err) }

user := User{Name: "dexter", Languages: languages}
err = db.Save(&user).Error
if err != nil { panic(err) }
```

The above code is trying to insert into languages table again. Because of this it triggers the `afterCreate` hook of Language model which is not expected.

```sql
 INSERT INTO `languages` (`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`name`,`id`) VALUES ('2024-01-22 19:44:37.247','2024-01-22 19:44:37.247','eng',55),('2024-01-22 19:44:37.247','2024-01-22 19:44:37.247','hin',57) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id`=`id`
```

How to avoid the `insert into languages` all-together and skip the `afterCreate` hook?

Comment: You can use `db.Omit("Languages").Create(&user)` to avoid inserting `Languages` again.

Comment: Hi, this is not creating records in user_languages.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the table where your list of languages is:

```golang
var languages []Language
err := db.Table("TableOfLanguages").Find(&languages).Error
```